# Perl SSL_verify_mode warning

Tags: perl, ssl

Got some code (simple RESTAPI query) migrated from an old Linux machine to a new Linux machine where Perl modules have been installed in an unknown way.

Using the following modules :

```
use JSON;
use REST::Client;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
use Getopt::Long;
```

And having `$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;`

Got this warning message when executing the script (but it works) :

```
*******************************************************************
 Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
 is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER
 possibly with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
 If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
 connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
 SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.
*******************************************************************
  at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 31.
```

Browsing internet leads me to a `IO::Socket::SSL` module, but it is in the same version than the older Linux (1.94).

`LWP::UserAgent` version is 6.05

So what would be the best way to avoid this nagging message ?

Comment: And REST::Client provides a default LWP::UserAgent when not set.

Comment: No, REST::Client does not have the ssl_opts flag when constructing.

Comment: Apologizes, but I don't kown how to create a LWP::Agent inside a REST::Client. If you know, please show me (I'm not a Perl guru...).

Comment: You are using an ancient version of IO::Socket::SSL and LWP::UserAgent, about 10 years old. Please upgrade your software stack. Don't expect support for such ancient software.

Comment: And after upgrading (if I can), what code I must use to avoid this message ? Since I don't construct LWP::UserAgent by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in the documentation for [`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client#useragent), just pass a custom user agent to the constructor, like so:

```perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use REST::Client;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->ssl_opts(
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
    SSL_ca_file     => '/path/to/ca_cert.pem'
);

my $client = REST::Client->new({
    host      => 'https://your.internal.resource',
    useragent => $ua
});
```

But, as noted in the comments (thanks @Steffen Ullrich). You should *really* update your `LWP::UserAgent`, and `IO::Socket::SSL` dists, then you wouldn't have to do any of this.